# Multivariate time series - is there notation to select all the variables, or do they all have to be written out?

Tags: r, model, time-series, tidyverse, forecasting

I'm working to build a multivariate time series to make predictions about labor in the United States. The fpp3 package is excellent, but I don't see a notation to model all the variables.

For example, in linear regression, it's possible to do this:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars.lm <-  lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
summary(mtcars.lm)
```

to model mpg on all the remaining variables, without having to write all the variables out explicity. Is there something similar in time series using the fpp3 package?

For example, this returns an error:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fpp3)
library(clock)

# Source: https://beta.bls.gov/dataViewer/view/timeseries/CES0000000001
All_Employees <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/InfiniteCuriosity/predicting_labor/main/All_Employees.csv', col_select = c(Label, Value), show_col_types = FALSE)
All_Employees <- All_Employees %>%
  rename(Month = Label, Total_Employees = Value)
All_Employees <- All_Employees %>%
  mutate(Month = yearmonth(Month)) %>% 
  as_tsibble(index = Month) %>% 
  mutate(Total_Employees_Diff = difference(Total_Employees))

index = All_Employees$Month

All_Employees <- All_Employees %>% 
  filter((Month >= start_month), (Month <= end_month))

# Source: https://beta.bls.gov/dataViewer/view/timeseries/CES0500000003
Average_Hourly_Earnings <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/InfiniteCuriosity/predicting_labor/main/Average_Hourly_Earnings.csv', col_select = c(Label, Value), show_col_types = FALSE)
Average_Hourly_Earnings <- Average_Hourly_Earnings %>%
  rename(Month = Label, Avg_Hourly_Earnings = Value)
Average_Hourly_Earnings <- Average_Hourly_Earnings %>% 
  mutate(Month = yearmonth(Month)) %>% 
  as_tsibble(index = Month) %>% 
  mutate(Avg_Hourly_Earnings_Diff = difference(Avg_Hourly_Earnings))

Average_Hourly_Earnings <- Average_Hourly_Earnings %>% 
  filter((Month >= start_month), (Month <= end_month))

Monthly_labor_data_small <- 
  tsibble(
    Month = All_Employees$Month,
    index = Month,
    'Total_Employees' = All_Employees$Total_Employees,
    'Avg_Earnings' = Average_Hourly_Earnings$Avg_Hourly_Earnings
  )

start_month_small = yearmonth("2020 Mar")
end_month_small = yearmonth("2022 Jan")  

Monthly_labor_data_small <- Monthly_labor_data_small %>% 
  filter((Month >= start_month_small), (Month <= end_month_small))


Monthly_labor_data_small %>% 
  model(
  linear = TSLM(Total_Employees ~ .,))
```

The error is: Error in TSLM(Total_Employees ~ ., ) : unused argument (alist())

But this runs fine if I list everything out:

```
fit <- Monthly_labor_data_small %>% 
  model(
  linear = TSLM(Total_Employees ~ Avg_Earnings + season() + trend()))

report(fit)
```

The full tsibble will have a large number of columns, is there a short way to list all of them, similar to what can be done in linear regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like

```r
resp <- "Total_Employees"
form <- reformulate(response = resp,
   c(setdiff(names(Monthly_labor_data_small), resp),
    "season()", "trend()"))
```

And then use `form` in your model. I haven't tried your examples -- if there are other variables (like a time index) that should not be explicitly included in the model  then the second argument to `setdiff()` should be `c(resp, "excluded_var2", "excluded_var3")`

Comment: Thanks. Question for clarification - that process did run, but it seems to require entering all the variables in the model. There are dozens of variables in the full time series, and many models. Is there a way in a time series to do something similar to what can be done in linear regression, such as (mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) where it is not necessary to write out all the variables? The sample time series above uses average earnings but there are many more variables in the models that will be used, including many models, and I'm looking for a shorter way to write the R code, if possible.

Comment: can't reproduce your example.  What are `start_month`, `end_month` ?  What do you mean by "include all the variables"? The example above *only* requires you to explicitly specify variable names that aren't in the names of the data set (or that should be excluded)

Comment: Thanks! The data sets from the government are a range of sizes, `start_month` and `end_month` make them all the same set of months, so the analysis will run. I missed that it only required the variables that are *not* in the data set. It ran correctly once I did that. Thank you very much, this will save a lot of time.